# Ошибка LNK2019 при использование метода из другого класса

Tags: c++

Выдаёт ошибку 
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall tickets::scan(class std::basic_ifstream > &)" (?scan@tickets@@QAEXAAV?$basic_ifstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) в функции "public: void __thiscall ListTickets::Read(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?Read@ListTickets@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

```
    #include "ListTickets.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include "tickets.h"

using namespace std;


ListTickets::ListTickets(unsigned int size)
{
    max_tickets = size;
    ticket = new tickets[size];
    num_tickets = 0;
    cout << "Вызвана конструкция класса" << endl;
    cout << "Выделенно объектов - " << max_tickets << endl;
    cout << "Загруженно книг - " << num_tickets << endl;
}


ListTickets::~ListTickets()
{
    max_tickets = 0;
    delete[] ticket;
    num_tickets = 0;
    cout << "\n Вызван дестурктор класса ListTickets:";
    cout << "\n     выделенная память освобожденна ";
}

void ListTickets::Add_Ticket(tickets aticket)
{
    if (num_tickets <= max_tickets)
    {
        ticket[num_tickets] = aticket;
        num_tickets++;
    }
}

void ListTickets::Read(string list)//Чтение книг из файла 
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(list);
    int size = 0;
    infile >> size; 
    //infile.get();
    cout << size;

    //tickets aticket;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //ticket[i].tickets::scan(infile);
        tickets new_ticket;
        new_ticket.scan(infile);
        Add_Ticket(new_ticket);
    }

}
Фрагмент tickets.cpp   
#include "tickets.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void tickets::scan(ifstream &file)
{
    file >> train >> station1 >> station2 >> dep_day
        >> dep_time >> coach >> seat >> price;
}

void tickets::display()
{
    cout << "===============================" << endl;
    cout << "Train:      " << train << endl;
    cout << "Station1:   " << station1 << endl;
    cout << "Station2:   " << station2 << endl;
    cout << "Dep_day:    " << dep_day << endl;
    cout << "Dep_time:   " << dep_time << endl;
    cout << "Coach       " << coach << endl;
    cout << "Seat        " << seat << endl;
    cout << "Price       " << price << endl;
}

float tickets::MaxTicket()
{
    return price;
}

string tickets::TrainNumber()
{
    return train;
}

string tickets::Time() {
    return dep_time;
}

int tickets::CoachNumber()
{
    return coach;
}

void tickets::write_to(ofstream &file)
{
    string train_, station1_, station2_, dep_day_, dep_time_;
    int coach_, seat_, price_;
    cout << "Enter Train...price";
    cin >> train_;
    cin >> station1_;
    cin >> station2_;
    cin >> dep_day_;
    cin >> dep_time_;
    cin >> coach_;
    cin >> seat_;
    cin >> price_;

    file << train_ << station1_ << station2_ << dep_day_
        << dep_time_ << coach_ << seat_ << price_;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в фрагменте метода void ListTickets::Read(string list)

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что что-то не так в файле tickets.h. Какой модификатор доступа у метода scan?

Comment: @Modus  
public, проблем с tickets.h не было до  добавления нового класса.

Comment: @Modus если вдруг интересно, строчку "#include "ListTickets.h" переместил под все includ 'ы и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

В ListTicket.cpp строчку "#include "ListTickets.h" переместил под все includ 'ы и всё заработало.